# Adding rows to datatable from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

i have a datagridview with a checkbox column.Now i have this code to add data from the dgvw to the datatable...

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim r As DataRow

dt.Columns.Add("a", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("b", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("c", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("d", Type.GetType("System.String"))

For i = 0 To dgvCarAccidentInjury.Rows.Count - 1
    r = dt.NewRow
    r("a") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
    r("b") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(1, i).Value.ToString
    r("c") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(2, i).Value.ToString
    r("d") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(3, i).Value.ToString
    dt.Rows.Add(r)
Next
```

Now, what i want is, when i check a row's checkbox, then the currentrow/checkedrow would be added to the datatable.What changes should i make to do so ? and in which even't should i apply the code ? should i use the code in the row prepaint event ? or currentcelldirtystatechanged event ?

Comment: Where does the data come from, a DB (your other code had SQL)?  If so there is no need to add data to the DGV or from DGV to the datatable.  Using databinding the DGV puts the data in the datatable for you.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

you must write a method triggered by click event:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim r As DataRow

sub new()

    dt.Columns.Add("a", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("b", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("c", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("d", Type.GetType("System.String"))


end sub





Private Sub Grid1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvCarAccidentInjury.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex < 0 OrElse e.RowIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim col = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)
    Dim row = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    If col.Name = "name_of_dgvcolumn_checkbox" Then
        Dim chkCell = DirectCast(row.Cells("name_of_dgvcolumn_checkbox"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

        dr.rows.clear()

       For i = 0 To dgvCarAccidentInjury.Rows.Count - 1
          if chkCell then
         r = dt.NewRow
          r("a") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
          r("b") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(1, i).Value.ToString
          r("c") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(2, i).Value.ToString
          r("d") = dgvCarAccidentInjury.Item(3, i).Value.ToString
          dt.Rows.Add(r)
         end if
      Next


    End If
End Sub
```